# Use cakeresque on xampp on windows

Tags: cakephp, xampp, cakephp-2.0, pcntl

I want to use cakeresque running on, and first I need to install PhpRedis.
When I install cakeresque with composer.json it gives me this error:

> kamisama/php-resque-ex 1.3.0 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension > pcntl is missing from your system.

So how do I install ext-pcntl on xampp in windows?

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it all, as it's not possible.

**http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php**

> **Note:**
> Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

---

**https://github.com/kamisama/php-resque-ex#warning**

> ### Warning
>
> php-resque requires the pcntl php extension, not available on Windows platform. Composer installation will fail if you're trying to install this package on Windows machine. If you still want to continue with the installation at your own risk, execute the composer install command with the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option.

---

**https://github.com/kamisama/php-resque-ex/pull/6**

---

So either force install `kamisama/php-resque-ex` and live with the limitations because of the missing PCNTL extension, or use a VM with an OS that is supported by PCNTL.